# Merge [packet-sniffers] and [sniffer]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Can we merge and synonymize [packet-sniffers](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/packet-sniffers) and [sniffer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sniffer) (probably [sniffer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sniffer) into [packet-sniffers](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/packet-sniffers))?
It's not like there are non-packet sniffers; "sniffer" refers only to a packet-sniffer.

Also, should [sniffing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sniffing) remain as it is? questions that are about the sniffing itself and not the sniffer program/software/tool should be tagged with [sniffing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sniffing). If we have both [sniffing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sniffing) and [packet-sniffers](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/packet-sniffers) then we should add tag wiki to make the difference clear.

I just found there's also [packet-capture](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/packet-capture) which is basically the definition of "sniffing", so I think we can merge and synonymize it as well.

Comment: I agree, especially given there's only a total of three questions designated `sniffer` and over twenty as `packet-sniffers`.  I believe `sniffer` is a terrible, unintuitive tag, and `packet-sniffer(s?)` should be the appropriate one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've merged [sniffer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sniffer) into  [packet-sniffers](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/packet-sniffers).

As for the second part of the question: <s>I'd almost merge</s> I merged  [packet-sniffers](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/packet-sniffers) into  [sniffing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sniffing) –  I mean, there's really not much of a difference anyway.

Comment: Great, thanks. I also thought they're too close.

Comment: I just found another similar tag, see my edit.

Comment: Don't forget to synonymize `[packet-capture]`.

Comment: Consider it done.